# Не выводится tv переменная Modx Revo

Tags: modx, revo

Создал дополнительную переменную, назвал ее ***lock***. Сделал доступной для шаблона. Создал документ, указал шаблон, в значение переменной написал ***123***. Перешел в шаблон и вывел ее

```
[[+tv.lock]]
```

Не выводится ничего. Что я делаю не так? Такой код

```
[[*titlepage]]
```

Выводит название страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблоне доступ к `tv` [следует делать с помощью `*`](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/template-variables) (также как к `pagetitle` или `longtitle`) - то есть вам надо так: `[[*lock]]`

Ваш вариант (`[[+tv.lock]]`) следует использовать, например в чанке при вызове `pdoPage` (`&tpl=...`)

Также, про синтаксис, подробнее можно почитать **[тут](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/tag-syntax)**